# How to Consume a Rails RABL API using Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, rabl

I am building a rails app using RABL that generates an API on my data controlled by Active Admin. It's a really simple API and I don't have much data yet, but I am newer to Angular.js and client side apps. Using rabl, I make an API on 2 objects. Here is my code so far;

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "100x100", :medium => "200x200", :large => "300x300" }, 
              :url  => "/system/members/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
              :path => ":rails_root/public/system/members/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
   validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type:     ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"] }

end
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @projects = Project.all

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render }
    end
end
```

end

**views/projects/index.html.rabl**

```
collection @projects
attributes :id, :title, :short_description, :long_description, :client, :image
```

**member.rb**

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :image

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "100x100", :medium => "200x200", :large => "300x300" }, 
              :url  => "/system/members/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
              :path => ":rails_root/public/system/members/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type:     ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"] }

end
```

**members_controller.rb**

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController

    def index
       @members = Member.all

        respond_to do |format|
           format.json { render }
        end
     end

  end
```

**views/members/index.html.rabl**

```
collection @members
attributes :id, :name, :title, :bio, :facebook, :twitter, :instagram, :linkedin, :dribbble, :image
```

**Angular;**

**app/assets/javascripts/app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("onyx", ["ngResource"]);

app.factory("Member", [ //member for the member object
  "$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/member/:name", {  //trying to just start by getting the name
      name: "@name"
    }, {
      update: {
        method: "GET"
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

**Update:** 
Thanks to [this](http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/04/22/angularjs-on-rails-4-part-1/) fantastic tutorial, I got everything working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since made a couple apps with angular and rails. Once you make your app, generate an API on all of your data. Once you do that Angular takes care of the rest. Using gems in my opinion is not the best, and you can use the rails asset pipeline to your advantage by using angular via CDN.

The best resources I have found to learn how to get rails and angular to play nice together, are these two tutorials:

1. http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/04/22/angularjs-on-rails-4-part-1/ (2 parts)
2. http://angular-rails.com (full app walkthrough + deployment and TDD)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [restmod](https://github.com/platanus/angular-restmod), an awesome ORM for angular.

**"Restmod creates objects that you can use from within Angular to interact with your RESTful API."**

First you need to install it. On [github](https://github.com/platanus/angular-restmod) it's well explained.

Then, you can define a model. For example:

```
module.factory('Project', function($restmod) {
   return $restmod.model('/projects');
});
```

Then, you can inject the Project model on your controller/service/etc and use it as following

```
$scope.projects = Project.$search();
```

On your view you can do something like this:

```
<pre>{{projects | json }}</pre>
```

to see the result.

With restmod you can:

- Create models and relations
- Perform CRUD operations
- Search and filter collections
- Create custom methods, mixins and hooks on your models.

All it's well explained on [github page](https://github.com/platanus/angular-restmod) and [documentation page](http://platanus.github.io/angular-restmod/)